# Missing Inbox Notification

Tags: bug, comments, inbox

I did not receive an inbox  notification for Martin Schroder's comment in [Greek Letters in Latex Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63453/greek-letters-in-latex-table) made 16 hours ago:

[image: Comment that did not end up in my inbox]

When I check my history I have:

[image: My inbox with that comment missing]

Clicking on the last one showing in the above list shows that it is marked as `yesterday` so the inbox notification from 16 hours ago should be above that.

[image: The last item in my inbox]

Comment: Similar problem that I had: [Didn't get notification for comment on my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110904) -- I'll notify the admin who dealt with my problem.